# min() and numpy.amin() return wrong minimum value

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataframe, df:

```
    nEvent  hitPos        hitType   layerZ  layerIndex  trackID
0   1   2.826200e-05    1   -16.0   0              0
1   1   -9.032680e-07   0   -21.0   1              0
2   1   1.956890e-03    1   131.0   2              0
3   1   -1.329020e-03   0   151.0   3              0
4   1   1.020050e-02    1   477.0   4              0
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
264977  10000   2.808240e-01    3   1467.4  13             1
264978  10000   2.760670e+01    1   1973.0  14             2
264979  10000   -3.631710e-01   1   1973.0  14             1
264980  10000   -1.561740e+01   0   1960.0  15             2
264981  10000   2.442910e-01    0   1960.0  15             1
```

I want to find the minimum from the 'hitPos' column which is evidently a negative number with the largest exponent.

What I have tried and failed to get the minimum:

1.

```
df[' hitPos'].min()
```

output: -47.4885

2.

```
np.amin(np.array(df[' hitPos']))
```

output: -47.4885

I tried asking the gpt, it told me to sort and then find the minimum using index.

3.

```
df['hitPos'].sort_values().iloc[0]
```

output: -47.4885

At this point I'm out of ideas. GPT suggests that there might be a problem with the data itself, in which case you can find the data file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14GSQYdOmiyJg2aia1Tt1AgWXb8-i3S6I/view?usp=share_link to try it for yourself.

Comment: "negative number with a negative exponent." Would it not be a negative number with a positive (or really as large as possible) exponent?

Comment: "which is evidently a negative number with a negative exponent." - No that would be the **largest** negative number. The minimum number in your case would have a positive exponent: `-1e1 < -1e-1` -> `-10 < -0.1`

Comment: It seems like -47.4885 is the correct answer when I tried as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, as pointed out by @Wombatz in his comment. The minimum value I'm getting is the right one. Thanks.